# Shape Names In Excel

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I have a VBA sub to create a few shapes, these shapes are then renamed to a cell value (B5:B15) and add text (C5:C15).

[image: How it looks in Excel]

The shapes gets created, renamed and the text gets added but when I try to connect them I get the "Object Required".
Can some one please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim s, conn  As Shape, i As Integer
Set w = ActiveSheet

For i = 5 To 7

    Set s = w.Shapes.AddShape(1, 800, i * 120 - 599, 100, 100)
    s.Name = Range("B" & i)
    s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("C" & i)
    s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 213)
    s.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 19

Next i

Set conn = w.Shapes.AddConnector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect A001, 1
    conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect A002, 1   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that would work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim s As Shape, conn As Shape, i As Long
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Set w = ActiveSheet

    Dim arr As Variant
    ReDim arr(5 To 7)
    For i = 5 To 7

        Set s = w.Shapes.AddShape(1, 800, i * 120 - 599, 100, 100)
        s.Name = Range("B" & i)
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("C" & i)
        s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 213)
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 19
        Set arr(i) = s
    Next i

    Set conn = w.Shapes.AddConnector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect arr(5), 1
    conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect arr(6), 1

End Sub
```

What is the difference?

- declaration of all variables - `s` is a Shape, `i` is a Long, `w` is a Worksheet;
- the declaration is forced by `Option Explicit`;
- a new variable `arr` is introduced, which keeps all the newly created forms. Thus the first form is kept under `arr(5)` and the last form is `arr(7)`;
- the `BeginConnect` and `EndConnect` need a variable which is a form. This is where we use the `arr(5)` to `arr(7)`;

---

You can also refer to the shape, by its name and the `Shapes()` collection. Thus, the last 3 lines should look like this:

```
Set conn = w.Shapes.AddConnector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect w.Shapes("A001"), 1
conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect w.Shapes("A002"), 1
```

Comment: Thanks by changing the last 3 lines to what you suggested it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: Great shout on how you explained `Option Explicit`. As far as `Connectors` are concerned.. this is new to me. Never used it but sounds like fun so will play with it :)